# PostgreSQL update JSONB without jsonb_set

Tags: postgresql, performance, json, postgresql-performance

Would there be any drawbacks to using a normal update statement to update a json(b) column like so:

```
update "events" set "properties" = '{"type":"graph"}'
```

Instead of using the jsonb_set function provided by PostgreSQL, which would turn into this statement:

```
update "events" set jsonb_set("properties", {'type'}, 'graph')
```

When using eg. an ORM, and calling .save() on a Model for which you've just updated a JSON field, the first method will be called, but as there is no mention of this way of doing things in the  PostgreSQL documentation, I fear this may have some drawbacks.

Given that I'm not incredibly familiar with anything regarding performance in databases, I thought I'd come and ask a question here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and you have a typo in path - instead of `{'type'}` there should be `'{type}'` I suppose

Comment: `update "events" set jsonb_set("properties", {'type'}, 'graph')` won't work, you'll have still to `set propertirs = jsonb_set("properties", {'type'}, 'graph')`

Answer (score 8):

**Update**: If the result value of jsonb is the same, then the only difference is `jsonb_set` would take additional CPU (and ms) to run. In both cases you run `SET column = VALUE`, but if resulted jsonb value is bifferent,both your statements are very much different, here is example.

sample:

```
t=# create table so63(j jsonb);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 6.290 ms
t=# insert into so63 select '{"a":0,"b":true}';
INSERT 0 1
Time: 1.137 ms
```

[jsonb_set](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
t=# update so63 set j = jsonb_set(j,'{a}','[2,3,4]');
UPDATE 1
Time: 1.699 ms
t=# select j from so63;
              j
-----------------------------
 {"a": [2, 3, 4], "b": true}
(1 row)
```

jsonb value changed at specified path! And now with `update .. set`:

```
Time: 0.278 ms
t=# update so63 set j = '{"a":[2,3,4]}';
UPDATE 1
Time: 0.918 ms
t=# select j from so63;
        j
------------------
 {"a": [2, 3, 4]}
(1 row)

Time: 0.241 ms
```

whole jsonb is overwritten. not just "a" key

Comment: However if in the code I merge the original JSON property with the changed JSON property so it passes the entire object to  `update ... set`, it'll end up being the same result but I assume it'll mess with any potential indexes set on any keys?

Comment: In both cases you run `SET column = VALUE`, so the simple update should be faster then jsonb_set. Indexes built on json are not maintained by jsonb_set, so no difference for them. or I'm totally wrong here?..